# Why is gradient descent and it's variants used instead of BFGS and L-BFGS for training neural nets?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, train

My understanding is that BFGS and L-BFGS solve the same type of optimization problems as GD and it's variants.

Why is GD the go to algorithm for training neural networks?

Comment: Quick answer: stochastic GD is simple and it works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use L-BFGS for optimization, it is included in some [libraries](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.LBFGS) as an optimizer, however it is very memory expensive algorithm, so many times it is more reasonable to use the gradient descent family.